# object undefined in second part of the form

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

When I say property I mean a house. Its a property site.

I'm creating an application with Angular (Laravel API on the backend). I have a 3 step form for submitting a property. In step one, in my advert service, I set the current property to be the model data that's returned. I can console.log this data just fine.

However when I console.log it on submission of the second part of the form. I get an undefined error. I did the ID from this object to send to the URL.

AdvertService

```
  createAdvert(userId: number, property: Property) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + userId + '/store', {property}).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
          this.currentProperty = response;
          console.log(response);
      })
    );
  }
```

I inject the service to the second part of the form. I try to call current property and console.log it and I get undefined.

```
  submitPayment() {
    const currentProperty = this.advertService.currentProperty.id;
    console.log(currentProperty);
    if (this.advertPaymentForm.value) {
      this.payment = (Object.assign({}, this.advertPaymentForm.value));
      console.log(this.payment);
      this.advertService.createAdvertPayment(currentProperty.id, this.payment).subscribe(data => {
        this.alertify.success('Success');
      }, error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
    }
  }
```

Property Model

```
export interface Property {
    id?: number;
    town?: string;
    county?: string;
    address: string;
    postocde: string;
    eircode: string;
    property_type: string;
    selling_type: string;
    price: number;
    bedrooms: number;
    bathrooms: number;
    size: number;
    building_energy_rating: string;
    description: string;
    user_id: number;
}
```

Edit. Console data of createAdvert

[image]

Any idea what the issue is here?

Full advert.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Property } from '../_models/property';
import { User } from '../_models/user';
import { Payment } from '../_models/payment';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdvertService {

  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl + 'advertisement/';
  currentProperty: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  createAdvert(userId: number, property: Property) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + userId + '/store', {property}).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
          this.currentProperty = response;
          console.log(this.currentProperty);
      })
    );
  }

  createAdvertPayment(propertyId: number, payment: Payment) {
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + propertyId + '/payment', {payment});
  }
}
```

Full advert-payment.component.ts (where the service is injected into)

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AdvertService } from '../_services/advert.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../_services/alertify.service';
import { AuthService } from '../_services/auth.service';
import { Payment } from '../_models/payment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-advert-payment',
  templateUrl: './advert-payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./advert-payment.component.css']
})

export class AdvertPaymentComponent implements OnInit {
  advertPaymentForm: FormGroup;
  model: any;
  payment: Payment;
  constructor(private advertService: AdvertService, private alertify: AlertifyService, public authService: AuthService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createAdvertPaymentForm();
  }

  createAdvertPaymentForm() {
    this.advertPaymentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      town: ['', Validators.required],
      county: ['', Validators.required],
      billing_address: ['', Validators.required],
      cardnumber: ['', Validators.required],
      month: ['', Validators.required],
      year: ['', Validators.required],
      cvv: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  submitPayment() {
    const currentProperty = this.advertService.currentProperty[0].id;
    console.log(currentProperty);
    if (this.advertPaymentForm.value) {
      this.payment = (Object.assign({}, this.advertPaymentForm.value));
      console.log(this.payment);
      this.advertService.createAdvertPayment(currentProperty.id, this.payment).subscribe(data => {
        this.alertify.success('Success');
      }, error => {
        this.alertify.error(error);
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Please share more details on your modal and what property are you talking about here?

Comment: Added the model. Property = House/Apartment. It's a property website

Comment: so you mean `console.log(this.payment);` is undefined?

Comment: Thats working fine. In the second code block at the top. The console.log(currentProperty) is undefined.

Comment: It would seem that the service that returns the `currentProperty` is returning an object where the `id` is undefined. The `id` *is optional* because it is declared as `id?:` (the question mark means it's optional), so you cannot rely on it being there. Make sure the service is returning all you need.

Comment: what does your response look like in network tab `this.currentProperty = response;` what do you see in console.log  at `createAdvert()`. It seems you do not get `id` on response object

Comment: @nircraft See the edit

Comment: still unclear as you say: **I inject the service to the second part of the form. I try to call current property and console.log it and I get undefined.**
Are you using the same service instance `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`? is your service provided at root? If you inject it again, it will be a new instance of service and you won't get `currentProperty` value from it

Comment: I have an angular service which handles the http requests. I initialize the service in the construct of my components and call the relevant service method in a function on the component which is hit when user submits the form.

Comment: They are different files fyi. Would I be better of using local storage?

Comment: @AndreMacNamara, how is the service made available to module? Do you provide it in AppModule  as a provider or you do it in each component? If you provide your service in AppModule, just injecting it in component constructor will take care of things. You can share your complete service declaration and i can give you an example. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53673474/9386929

Comment: is this perhaps an async issue? `this.advertService.currentProperty.id;` is called before `createAdvert` has finished? Wild guess...

Comment: @nircraft It's in the app module. I'll include the files in the op

Answer (score 0):

So seeing the code it appears you never subscribed to `createAdvert(userId: number, property: Property)` in your component and hence the `currentProperty` never got the value from the HTTP call.

Make sure to subscribe to this in your component `OnInit`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.createAdvertPaymentForm();
    this.advertService.createAdvert(YourUserId, UserProperty).subscribe(data => {
         console.log(data); // this will give you `currentProperty` data
     });
  }
```

> In angular, `http` request returns observable, so you need to `subscribe`. If there aren't any subscriber to the `observable`, **it won't be executed**

Comment: OP must somewhere subscribe to the function, as they are showing the console log of result. The question is just incomplete, we don't know where this function is called...

Comment: @AJT_82, Yeah, you are right..We can't know for sure if he is not sharing the minimal, reproducible example.